# How to replace/update a file on Google Drive with PyDrive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, pydrive

My application needs to upload some files daily, updating those that already exist.

I know that if I pass the ID of existing files, they will be updated, but I was wondering if there's some more clever solution for this.

```
def upload_file(path, folder, filename, drive):

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print('Arquivo não encontrado: {}'.format(filename))
        return

   

    id_folder_destiny = get_id_from_gdrive(folder)
    file_metadata = {'title': filename, 
        'parents': [{'kind': 'drive#fileLink',
        'id': id_folder_destiny}]}
    file = drive.CreateFile(file_metadata)
       
    file.SetContentFile(path)
    file.Upload()
```

That code above is without the 'search existing ID'.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have found for updating a Google drive file is by uploading the file with the ID stated in the `drive.CreateFile` function, like you said.
Here is my code for downloading and then overwriting the specific file.

```
def upload_file_to_drive(file_id, local_path):
    """Overwrites the existing Google drive file."""
    update_file = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
    update_file.SetContentFile(local_path)
    update_file.Upload()

def download_drive_file(file_id, save_path):
    """Downloads an existing Google drive file."""
    download_file = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
    download_file.GetContentFile(save_path)
```

In use with an OOP class:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

def get_google_drive_auth(self):
    """Initilaizes the Google drive 'drive' object. """
    gauth = GoogleAuth()

    # Try to load saved client credentials
    gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("path/to/your/credentials/file")

    if gauth.credentials is None:
        # Authenticate if they're not there
        gauth.GetFlow()
        gauth.flow.params.update({'access_type': 'offline'})
        gauth.flow.params.update({'approval_prompt': 'force'})
        gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

    elif gauth.access_token_expired:
        # Refresh them if expired
        gauth.Refresh()
    else:
        # Initialize the saved creds
        gauth.Authorize()

    # Save the current credentials to a file
    gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("path/to/your/credentials/file")  

    self.drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    
def upload_file_to_drive(self, file_id, local_path):
    """Overwrites the existing Google drive file."""
    update_file = self.drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
    update_file.SetContentFile(local_path)
    update_file.Upload()
    
def download_drive_file(self,file_id, save_path):
    """Downloads an existing Google drive file."""
    download_file = self.drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
    download_file.GetContentFile(save_path)  # Save Drive file as a local file
```